# POST request doesn't work with Hardhat task

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I'm using Hardhat on NextJS.
And I don't know how to run Hardhat task from my API

My API:

```
//pages/api/verify/index.ts
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

import { task } from "hardhat/config";

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  try {
    const { contractAddress } = req.body;

    console.log("Args:", contractAddress);

    await task("verifyContract", "Verify factory contracts").setAction(
      async (taskArguments, hre, runSuper) => {
        console.log("Task verifyContract is running");
        const { contractAddress } = taskArguments;

        await hre.run("verify:verify", {
          address: contractAddress,
          constructorArguments: [
            "10000000000000000",
            "0x7600120a741b0969d41cf3804e373665cfd11b4",
          ],
        });

        console.log("Task verifyContract is done");
      }
    );

    console.log("Task skipped");

    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Server response: 200",
      contractAddress: contractAddress,
      taskCompleted: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ message: "Error" });
  }
}
```

My POST request:

```
const handleVerifyContract = async () => {
    const contractAddress = "0x4C51578AD78478c124B34Fb5812A87F81a47108c";

    try {
      console.log("Call function handleVerifyContract");

      const response = await fetch("/api/verify", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          contractAddress,
        }),
      });

      console.log("POST:", JSON.stringify({ contractAddress }));

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        // setVerificationId(data.verificationId);
        console.log("Server response:", data.contractAddress);
      } else {
        throw new Error("Failed to verify contract.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

I send my post request and get this:

- I send contractAddress correctly and get it from API response
- On server side I get logs: "Args: 0x4C51578AD78478c124B34Fb5812A87F81a47108c" and Task skipped

I tried a lot of edits, and don't know why I can't run this task.
If I write something like "await run("verifyContract") or something like this - I'll get error:

```
You probably tried to import the "hardhat" module from your config or a file imported from it.
This is not possible, as Hardhat can't be initialized while its config is being defined.

To learn more about how to access the Hardhat Runtime Environment from different contexts go to https://hardhat.org/hre
```